# Why am I seeing the grub menu?

Tags: boot, grub2

My /etc/default/grub on Ubuntu 18.10 (no dualboot) looks like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I am still seeing the grub menu every time I boot and it stays until I select 'ubuntu' and hit enter. No timeout. I just want the machine to boot the first kernel entry without any delay. What am I missing?

I did change GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false" to GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true" but I still see the menu.

Comment: `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` should be set `true`

Comment: This seems like a duplicate but it's a bug. The latest grub2 updated introduces this bug. It has been reported, a fixed has been created, and soon it'll come for everybody. Check out https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1814403

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I made this change and did update-grub. I still have the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I've been digging a bit deeper and found that this prevents the menu from showing:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```